# How to use each element in the list to check and locate the matching value from a data set?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I want to retrieve values from a data set that matches a certain value. The ".loc" method is working fine if I give one value at a time. But when trying to get the value from a list nothing is happening.

The below script work fine.

```
df.loc[df.domains=="IN"]
```

The below script is not. I want to use each item from the list to match and get the desired data frame from the data set

```
list=[""AE","AU","BE","BR","CN","DE","EG","ES","FR","IN","IT","JP","MX","NL","PL","SE","SG","UK"]

for i in list:
      a=f'"{i}"'  
      print(a)  
      df.loc[df.domains==a]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `a=f'"{i}"'` try `a = list[i]`
You need to access the list in position i in order to get the location you desire.

Also I noticed that in list you have extra " in the beginning. It might give you a syntax error

Comment: Hello, Thank you for replying back.  I've tried using  "a=list[i]" but it is showing an error. "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str". Please advice.

Comment: This is happening because in  `for i in list:` , i is defined to be the location name. So you have two options: either set `a = i` or define i to be the position number by: `for i in range(len(list)):`